# Preload @Font-Face Fonts to stop Firefox Flicker/Delay

Tags: fonts, embedded-fonts

Has anyone figured out how to preload the fonts to stop the flicker/delay?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330825/preloading-font-face-fonts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fighting the FOUT in Firefox : 
Firefox starts re - rendering the text AFTER window.load event.
So what I did is hide the content like Paul Irish does, but AFTER window.load I still wait 200 millisec (to give FF time for the real rendering), and then show the page.

My site has a lot of images, so to speed this up, I first send the page allmost without content, and then get the content with an ajax call. 
That's a lot of work to satisfie FF, but the results are good.

This is my paul irish variant, note I use negative text-indent in stead of visibility to serve the visitor at least the layout faster:

```
    <script>
    (function(){
  var d = document, e = d.documentElement, s = d.createElement('style');
  if (e.style.MozTransform === ''){ // gecko 1.9.1 inference
   // s.textContent = 'body{visibility:hidden}';
    s.textContent = 'body{text-indent:-9999px}';
    e.firstChild.appendChild(s);
    function f()
    { 
    var ffrendertime = setTimeout ( function(){s.parentNode && s.parentNode.removeChild(s)} , 200 ); 
    }
    addEventListener('load',f,false);
    setTimeout(f,2000); 
  }
})();
    </script>
```

Comment: This was really useful, I changed it to 600 instead of 200 as the font wasnt loading quick enough. EDIT: Later changed it back after I stopped using the Google font api - too slow.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just hide the text with a wf-inactive class on the html tag and an inline style in header that hides all descendant nodes of .wf-inactive that contain a text element rather than do a wacky workaround that loads text in after DOM load.  Thinking this would be better for SEO than loading the physical content via AJAX.

Answer (score 18):

There has been a lot of discussion regarding this issue which Paul Irish calls FOUT (flash of unstyled text). There are numerous ways to limit this by

1 Putting CSS at the very top of the page before any script tags

2 Minimizing the size of the font file

3 Browser Caching with far future expires headers

4 Gziping your CSS and font file (WOFF can't be gzipped)

Paul Irish has a great article about this: [Fighting the @font-face FOUT](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/)

Steve Souders also has a great article on his High Performance Websites blog: [@font-face and performance](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/)