# Using Google Web Fonts...font is "flashing" on load in Firefox. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: firefox, font-face, webfonts

I'm using Google Web Fonts on a site I'm developing. Everything is fine on all the browsers I care about EXCEPT for Firefox. Take a look:

http://033ac16.netsolhost.com/

Note that I'm I'm using [HTML5 Boilerplate Template for Wordpress, by Jefferey Sambells](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/10/25/html5-boilerplate-wordpress-theme/).

Note also that I've tried the [Fighting FOUT code by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) to no avail (maybe I implemented it incorrectly?)

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix that seems to work:

[Preload @Font-Face Fonts to stop Firefox Flicker/Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379645/preload-font-face-fonts-to-stop-firefox-flicker-delay)

The first page load within the site still experiences a slight "flash" but each sub page afterward looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything's wrong with your code - `@font-face`'d fonts are going to flash while they download the font file. It may happen that Firefox isn't caching your font (for whatever reason) or maybe it's just slower downloading it.