# Controlling @font-face Browser Download

Tags: css, browser, download, font-face

When using @font-face in css, the browser loads my page's text before the font, which results in the font jumping from one style to another (from Arial to myfont). When using condensed fonts, for example, the problem is very pronounced visually.

I only want to display the one font that I have chosen with @font-face. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preload @Font-Face Fonts to stop Firefox Flicker/Delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379645/preload-font-face-fonts-to-stop-firefox-flicker-delay)

Answer (score 2):

It's called FOUT the best way to handle it in my experience is by using Google's font loader:

https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader

Essentially what you do is let the page load normally (during which the body is hidden or styled font blocks are hidden, your choice), once they are loaded a class is added to the body of the page, this triggers the display of the styled fonts.

The script adds these classes so you can style appropriately:

```
 .wf-inactive - failed to load
 .wf-loading - during load
 .wf-active - loaded fine
```

The only downfall is that it requires Javascript..

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty well-known issue in some browsers (Firefox 3.5/3.6, IE 7-9). [WebINK](http://www.extensis.com/en/WebINK/fout-b-gone/) has a JavaScript file available which will allow you to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a **Flash Of Unstyled Text** and is due, as you mentioned, to the font files loading in tandem with the rest of the page, whose text will be styled with default or fallback fonts until the new font face is loaded and can be applied.

It appears that the best way to minimize the occurrence of this effect is to minimize the time the client spends loading your custom fonts. Two measures you can take to accomplish this are [compressing your font files](http://www.phpied.com/gzip-your-font-face-files/) via gZip and specifying your font files for long-term caching  by a viewer's browser for subsequent views via a [far-future expires header](http://cjohansen.no/en/apache/using_a_far_future_expires_header).

If the FOUT is still pretty jarring for your users, you can specify a similarly-shaped font which is likely to be installed on most viewers' machines as a fallback to keep your page size relatively consistent as the custom font loads. For example, for your condensed font, most viewers already have Impact as an available font, or Arial Narrow, both of which adhere to a 'condensed' style.

And if all else fails, you can always style the entire text of your document with `color: rgba(0,0,0,0)` and use JavaScript to remove that rule at the end of a timer.