# HTML pre-load font and use it in css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm aware that all of you know, if we do this in our .css file:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "Akrobat-Regular";
        src: url('/assets/Akrobat-Regular.otf') format("truetype");
      }
      body {
        color: #1c1c1c;
        font-family: "Akrobat-Regular" !important;
      }
```

Browser will do additional request to download font, and as a result there will be a short amount of time when default font will be used and then they will be substituted with new downloaded.

I found this way to preload font, but really don't know how top use downloaded font without additional request (don't worry, ti as slim syntax):

```
    link rel='preload' href='/assets/Akrobat-Regular.otf' as='font' type='font/otf'

    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'

    css:
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Akrobat-Regular";
        src: url('/assets/Akrobat-Regular.otf') format("truetype");
      }
      body {
        color: #1c1c1c;
        font-family: "Akrobat-Regular" !important;
      }
```

Comment: IMO title does not reflect the actual question

Comment: How you think it will be more reflect question?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I think the title is appropriate here and reflect the idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683378/7314900

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [pre loaded fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) without creating a font-face as well.

```
<link rel="preload" href="your_font_file" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Just mention the font family to use it:

```
font-family: "your_font";
```

This way you don't need to put an additional request, as you have already loaded the font in your document.

*Check the below example:*

```css
div.rob {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preload" href="https://github.com/FontFaceKit/roboto/blob/gh-pages/fonts/Regular/Roboto-Regular.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="rob">
  Hola in roboto
</div>

<div>
  Normal font
</div>
```

Comment: `<link rel=preload> must have a valid 'as' value`, but font still is not loading :( You have the same warning

Comment: The font loads in the example perfectly, I don't see any error. I am using chrome btw.

Comment: I can't make it to work, in my example, when I `href='/assets/Akrobat-Regular.otf'` trying to get this font I receive status 200 (it's downloaded). But when I do `body { font-family: ''Akrobat-Regular.otf" }` font is not changing, even if I do this in `.css` or in `<head>` tag

Comment: omit the `.otf` in font-family. Just use the name.