# Using preload with Create React App

Tags: css, reactjs, font-face, create-react-app, preload

I'm trying to use `preload` for a font in a project that was bootstrapped with `create-react-app`.

I added this tag to my index.html file:

`<link rel="preload" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/myFontFile.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2">`

But my problem is that I don't know how to reference this font file from my CSS (in the `@font-face` url). The CSS file is not in the `public` folder.

A different option might be to put the font file into `/src` but then I don't know what the file name of my font file is in the `preload` tag because it gets assigned a random id when there is a new version of it & webpack builds the project.

I know that I can put the CSS together with the font file into the `public` folder but that will mean that this CSS doesn't get bundled.

What is the best approach to get `preload` to work with `create-react-app` (no eject) and have the CSS with the `@font-face` declaration bundled together with the other CSS files?

Or if this is not really possible: what are my alternatives where I can get a similar behaviour to preload for my font loading?

Answer (score 4):

You should check out this [article from CSS tricks for font optimization](https://css-tricks.com/three-techniques-performant-custom-font-usage) first, but I believe your font should be in your public dir when using create react app. I use mine along with the [LoadCSS library](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS)

```
<link rel="preload" href="./style/Atlan-Bold.woff" as="font" type="font/woff2" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" crossorigin>
```

directly after this call I have my css file which references this font as so:

```
<link rel="preload" href="./style/style.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/style.css"></noscript>
```

and in this css I reference

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Atlan Bold';
  src: url('Atlan-Bold.woff') format('woff')
}
```

additionally here is some info for using in Chrome: [Preloading fonts in Chrome with 'preload' link directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616709/preloading-fonts-in-chrome-with-preload-link-directive)

Comment: And your stylesheet is then also in the public folder? (Which is a solution that I referenced in my question but is not preferred)

Comment: I have minimal, critical css directly in the HTML header, I also have a preloaded css file from the public folder(along with the WOFF font) within the HTML body. No repeated css - just diversified/split based on need and lading requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add this answer since I was dealing with a similar issue with my create-react-app. My app has an html5 canvas which uses a custom font, but the font would only download after the first rendering of the canvas which meant that the user would see the wrong font until they triggered 2 updates to the canvas.

I found the [webfontloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader) utility (developed by TypeKit and Google) which can load fonts on-demand (along with a bunch of other neat stuff).

```
npm i webfontloader @types/webfontloader
```

In my case, I wanted to load the font only when the user navigates to the url path which contained the canvas, so I added this `useEffect` code snippet to the relevant functional component (it triggers only once on the first component load):

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

export default function CanvasDraw() {
  // trigger download of custom font immediately on 1st render so that canvas uses it
  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      custom: {
        families: ['My CustomFontFamily'],
      },
    });
  }, []);

  ...

  return ( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this can solve the font issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.fonts.load("12px Merriweather").then(() => setIsReady(true));
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add react-meta-tags by `npm i react-meta-tags`

```js
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

<MetaTags>
    <title>Any Title Optional</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="/assets/font-family-name.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin />
</MetaTags>
```