# How can we preload fonts in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, fonts, angular-cli, preload

Should we include the fonts in **index.html** file with `rel="preload"` like the below code or can we configure this in Angular CLI to preload all the fonts required?
Please suggest me a better solution as I can see it takes multi-second page load time suggested in Google Analysis.

```html
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Semibold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Heavy.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Medium.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff2" as="font" crossorigin>
```

Comment: check these url, you might get help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330825/preloading-font-face-fonts
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616709/preloading-fonts-in-chrome-with-preload-link-directive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preloading @font-face fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330825/preloading-font-face-fonts)

Comment: the closer to standard HTML you can get: do that one, even if the framework you're using has its own bespoke way of doing things. Because unless those bespoke solutions compile down to "plain HTML", the plain HTML solution is always the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Preconnect** to the font file origin.
2. **Preload** the font stylesheet asynchronously with low priority.
3. **Asynchronously** load the font stylesheet and font file after the content has been rendered with JavaScript.
4. Provide a **fallback font** for users with JavaScript turned off.

Example::

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Merriweather&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Merriweather&display=swap" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
<noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Merriweather&display=swap" />
</noscript>
```

For your reference : [Link to Harry Roberts explanation on fonts loading](https://csswizardry.com/2020/05/the-fastest-google-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

Including multiple preload links for each font file can bloat your html file and make it harder to manage.

**1.** You can create a service in angular to handle font preloading. This will allow flexibility.

**2**. You can also configure your angular.json file

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts",
      "output": "/webfonts/"
    }
]
```

**3.** If the fonts you have are not part of application standard assets, you can use a service as

In service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FontPreloadingService {
  preloadFonts(fontUrls: string[]) {
    fontUrls.forEach((url) => {
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'preload';
      link.as = 'font';
      link.href = url;
      link.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      document.head.appendChild(link);
    });
  }
}

Preload the fonts in your component
```

In app.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FontPreloadingService } from './font-preloading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private fontPreloadingService: FontPreloadingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const fontUrls = [
      './assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Semibold.woff2',
      './assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.woff2',
      // Add other font URLs as needed
    ];

    this.fontPreloadingService.preloadFonts(fontUrls);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I could come up with to force the browser to pre-download the font files, is to actually use the font.

Create a `font-preload.css` file ie. `/assets/fonts/Lato/font-preload.css`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(Lato-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(Lato-Medium.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(Lato-Semibold.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(Lato-Bold.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(Lato-Heavy.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(Lato-Black.woff2) format('woff2');
}

/* font pre-load class with off-screen invisible text */
.f-pl {
    position: absolute;
    top: -14000px;
    left: -14000px;
    font-size: 0.001px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    color: transparent
}

/* For each font, create a class with the font-family and its weight
   which matches the font file to be downloaded */
.f-pl.lato-regular {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 400;
}
.f-pl.lato-medium {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 500;
}
.f-pl.lato-semibold {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 600;
}
.f-pl.lato-bold {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 700;
}
.f-pl.lato-heavy {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 800;
}
.f-pl.lato-black {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Include the css stylesheet in the end of the `<head>` tag and also elements with the `f-pl` class for each font in the `<body>` tag:

```
    <link href="assets/fonts/Lato/font-preload.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- use the fonts so the browser downloads the font files -->
    <a class="f-pl lato-regular">1</a>
    <a class="f-pl lato-medium">1</a>
    <a class="f-pl lato-semibold">1</a>
    <a class="f-pl lato-bold">1</a>
    <a class="f-pl lato-heavy">1</a>
    <a class="f-pl lato-black">1</a>

    <app-root></app-root>
```

The `.f-pl` class will move the tiny transparent text off-screen and out of view with its `position: absolute;` and `top: -14000px; left: -14000px;`.

If you have fonts with `unicode-range:` for specific unicode ranges, just create a class for that font + weight then instead of `1` as the character, use a character in that specific unicode range.

This also works for Material Icons/Symbols for instance:

```
.f-pl.material-symbols-outlined {
    font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined'
}
.f-pl.material-symbols-sharp {
    font-family: 'Material Symbols Sharp'
}
.f-pl.material-symbols-rounded {
    font-family: 'Material Symbols Rounded'
}
```

Then in the `<body>` tag:

```
<a class="f-pl material-symbols-outlined">1</a>
<a class="f-pl material-symbols-sharp">1</a>
<a class="f-pl material-symbols-rounded">1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option you can try by using `APP_INITIALIZER` like this:

Create a FontProvider:

```
export const FontProvider = () => {
    const fonts = [
        {
            family: "Lato Regular",
            src: "./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff2",
            options: {
                weight: '400',
                style: 'normal'
            }
        },
        {
            family: "Lato Semibold",
            src: "./assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Semibold.woff2",
            options: {
                weight: '600',
                style: 'normal'
            }
        }
    ];

    for (const {family, src, options} of fonts) {
        const font = new FontFace(family, src, options);
        font.load()
            .then(() => document.fonts.add(font))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

Now, add this FontProvider to you `app.module.ts` file :

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FontProvider } from './font.provider.ts'
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: FontProvider,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will work 100% and let me know if you need some other suggestion or help.

Answer (score -2):

For this implementation in angular, you should use third-party dependency to load the fonts.

use **[webfontloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader)**

> npm i webfontloader

After that load your custom font like this

```
 WebFont.load({
  custom: {
    families: [""Lato"]
  }
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

**For this implementation in angular, you should use third-party dependency to load the fonts.,Find centralized, trusted content and collaborate around the technologies you use most.,Connect and share knowledge within a single location that is structured and easy to search.
After that load your custom font like this**

```
   WebFont.load({
              custom: {
                 families: [""
                    Lato "]
                 }
              });
```

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answers?