# How to set rel=preload in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I import fonts like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:fname;
    src:url(../fonts/fname.woff) format('woff'),
    url(../fonts/fname.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight:400;
}
```

Also when I analysis my website using SEO tools (ex. google page speed insight), they suggest using `rel="preload"`for those fonts. Since I don't use HTML for importing that fonts to the page, any idea how can I use that HTML attribute using CSS?

Comment: What do you mean of  `I don't use HTML for importing those fonts` ? you have to use `rel="preload"` on your `<link>` tag, where you import css that include your fonts. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)

Comment: Well, I don't have any `<link>` tag for that font.

Comment: If you are using a framework such as bootstrap, they import the fonts in their css files ... so you are not necessarily doing this on purpose, but the framework is doing it.

Comment: Not purely in css, may be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330825/preloading-font-face-fonts/46830425

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="../fonts/fname.woff" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Also you can check [this post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/web-fonts-in-2018-f191a48367e8/)