# Avoid the FOUT problem in NextJS apps by preloading the fonts

Tags: next.js, fonts, font-face, preloading

I have a Next.JS application (not v13 yet!) and I am encountering the dreaded [FOUT](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) (flash of unstyled text) problem. I understand that [one of the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330825/preloading-font-face-fonts) is to preload the fonts directly in the HTML `<header>` in the `index.html`. My problem is how do I do that considering that the `index.html` page is being created on build-time by Next? Where do I add the `<link ...>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use next/head component as described in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

Comment: But the question I am asking is .. WHERE to place things <head> component?

Comment: Next generates htmls for all files in pages/ folder. You can put it in the _app.tsx to have it on all pages, example [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) . Or add it directly to index.tsx if you want it to be only on specific (index) page.